# Reading real*8 variable with value 0 with real*4 results a large number in fortran without warning

Tags: fortran

Reading real*4 variable with value 0 with real*8 results a large number, sometimes without warning.

I'm not good at Fortran. I was just running a Fortran code I got from someone else, and it made a segmentation fault. While I was debugging it, I found that one of the subroutines is reading a variable with value 0 defined with real*8 as real*4 results a large value.

I tried to reproduce it with simple code, but compiler showed a warning for the argument mismatch. I had to nest codes to reproduce the suppressed warning in simple code, but I'm not sure what's the exact condition for suppressed warning.

Actually, for some reason, I'm suspecting it may be the problem of my compiler, as the code (not the example code, original code) ran fine on the PC of the person who gave me the code.

**file `hello.f`:**

```
  implicit none
  call sdo()
  END
```

**file `test.f`:**

```
  subroutine sdo()
  implicit none
  real*4 dsecs
  dsecs=0
  write(0,*) dsecs
  call sd(dsecs)
  return
  end
```

**file `test2.f`:**

```
  subroutine sd(dsecs)
  implicit none
  real*8 dsecs
  write(0,*) dsecs
  return
  end
```

**compilation and execution:**

```
$ gfortran -o hello hello.f test.f test2.f
$ ./hello
```

**Expected result:**

```
0. 00000000
0. 0000000000000000
```

**Actual results:**

```
0. 00000000
-5.2153889789423361E+223
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not the problem of the compiler. It is the problem of the code. Your code did issue a warning for me that you were doing something nefarious, as it should. The subroutine that thinks `dsecs` is 4 bytes long sent 4 bytes. The subroutine that thinks `dsecs` is 8 bytes long looked at 8 bytes. What's in the other 4 bytes? Who knows. How does it look like when the two get mixed together? Probably not what you want. It's like accidentally getting served a scoopful of half icecream and half garbage: unlikely to taste the way you thought.

This is one of those problems that are very simply solved with that classic joke: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do *this*!" - "Then... don't do that."

EDIT: Sorry, I cheated. I didn't compile them as separate programs. When I do, I don't get warnings. This is also normal - at compilation step, you didn't specify how foreign subroutines look so it couldn't complain, and at linking step compiler doesn't check any more.

Comment: No it didn't issue a warning when I nested subroutines like that.

Comment: As I said, mine did. Yours might have missed it, or had the warnings off; I don't know what your compiler is, nor how you ran it. Crucially, the error is in the code; the compiler might make debugging difficult if it doesn't report a warning, but it's still your error.

Comment: When I write the code in a single script, my compiler issue a warning. But when I write code like that, it doesn't. Do you still think it's a code problem?

Comment: Yes. You are not supposed to run a red light, whether or not there are police around. You are not supposed to pass a real*4 parameter where real*8 is expected, whether or not compiler complains.

Comment: I see your point, but still I can not see the logic. If police catch red light crossing arbitrarily, they are not reliable.

Comment: This is not police catching red light crossing. This is you crashing into another car because you don't obey the laws :P. Your friend was lucky he missed it. The police catching the red light is the compiler's warning telling you what you're doing should not be done.

Comment: The code is also non-standard in other ways, real*4/8 is not and has never been part of Fortran and each compiler is free to interpret it as it wants. But more relevantly if the code was not written in a style appropriate for the last millennium and instead used module or contained subprograms you would not have this problem.

Comment: Just to be clear: if the code is in separate files, there will be no warning issued. The linker will then just match the subroutine names without any warning as the linker is not aware of the arguments. Some compilers will attempt to make interfaces and modules that could catch these problems (such as `ifort`)